# <img> tag is not able to render image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a few bootstrap cards. On clicking them, I am redirecting to the other page where I am using data passed through NavLink and rendering it.

Here is my code.

Destination.jsx

```
<div className="row mt-3">
  {firstRowData.map((country, index) => (
    <div className="col-md-3" key={index}>
      <NavLink
        to={`/country/${country.id}`}
        state={{ data: country.id }}
      >
        { Card code }
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

CountryInfo.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import countryData from "./data";

function CountryInfo() {
  const location = useLocation();
  let countryId = location.state?.data;

  if (countryData) {
    const image1Url = countryData[countryId].images.image1;
    console.log("Image1 -->", image1Url);
    return (
      <div className="">
        <img
          src={image1Url}
          alt=""
          style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        />
      </div>
    );
```

I have a data.jsx file which contains json data.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Singapore",
    url: "images/card_singapore.jpg",
    price: "$ 300",
    day: 5,
    images: {
      image1: "images/new_0.jpg",
      image2: "images/new_1.jpg",
      image3: "images/new_2.jpg",
      image4: "images/new_3.jpg",
    },
  },
  // some more data.....
```

Through below code I am able to print correct image address.

> console.log("Image1 -->", image1Url);

But `img` tag is not able to render the image. Why is this happening ?

**One Observation :**

If I call `contryInfo.jsx` directly from `App.js` then I am able to see the image. `img` tag properly renders image

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <CountryInfo />
      <Pages />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image source paths are using a *relative* path since they do not start with a `"/"` character, e.g. they are source *relative* to the current URL path. When you render `CountryInfo` at the root of the app the (*assumed*) path is just `"/"` so the relative paths in the PUBLIC directory work, e.g. `"/public/images/new_0.jpg"`, but when `CountryInfo` is rendered on `"/country/:countryId"` the images are sourced relative to *this* path, e.g. `/public/country/0/images/new_0.jpg"`.

Either update the data to use an *absolute* path:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Singapore",
    url: "/images/card_singapore.jpg",
    price: "$ 300",
    day: 5,
    images: {
      image1: "/images/new_0.jpg",
      image2: "/images/new_1.jpg",
      image3: "/images/new_2.jpg",
      image4: "/images/new_3.jpg",
    },
  },
  ...
];
```

Or prepend this to the image source string when rendering:

```
function CountryInfo() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const countryId = location.state?.data;

  if (countryData) {
    const image1Url = countryData[countryId].images.image1;
    return (
      <div className="">
        <img
          src={`/${image1Url}`}
          alt="country"
          style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  ...
```

An additional side note: Since the `country.id` is already used in the URL path when navigating, there's no point really in passing ***only*** the same `country.id` value in route state. Just use the path segment to get the passed country id. Define the route rendering `CountryInfo` to have a dynamic path segment, e.g. `path="/country/:countryId"`.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/country/:countryId" element={<CountryInfo />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Pages />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

```
<div className="row mt-3">
  {firstRowData.map((country) => (
    <div className="col-md-3" key={country.id}>
      <NavLink to={`/country/${country.id}`}>
        { ...Card code... }
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function CountryInfo() {
  const countryId = useParams();

  const { image1, name } = countryData[countryId]?.images ?? {};

  if (image1) {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <img
          src={image1}
          alt={name}
          style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  ...
```